# Defining an inverse function

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, functions, inverse-function

Consider the map $f:\mathbb{R}^n\to\mathbb{R}^{n-1}$ that maps $x\mapsto y$ defined as 
\begin{align}
f(x_1,x_2,...,x_n)=(y_1,y_2,...,y_{n-1})
\end{align}
where $y_i = x_i - x_n, \forall i \in \{1,...,n-1\}$.
Obviously, this map is not invertible.
Can we "define" an inverse for $f$? For instance, we can define
\begin{align}
f^{-1}(y_1,y_2,...,y_{n-1})=(x_1,x_2,...,x_{n-1},0).
\end{align}
where $x_i = y_i, \forall i \in \{1,...,n-1\}$.
Can we say that this "defined" inverse function is smooth? If yes, can we conclude that the restriction of $f$ to $\mathbb{R}^n\times\{0\} $ is a homeomorphism?

Comment: I am confused. Is the $f$ in the last sentence a different function to the starting $f$, e.g. a restriction to $\mathbb{R}^{n-1}\times\{0\}$? Otherwise, how can it be a homeomorphism?

Comment: Sorry for the confusion. Yes, I mean the restriction. I revise the question.

Comment: Your function as is written is not well defined. It maps $\Bbb{R}^n$ into $\mathcal{P}(\Bbb{R}^{n-1})$. Possibly it is a notation mistake, but it would be clearer if it is written as follows: $$f(x_1,x_2,\dots,x_n)=(y_1,y_2,\dots,y_{n-1})$$ where $y_i=x_i-x_n$ for all $i\in\{1,2,\dots,n-1\}$.

Comment: @Azif00 . Thanks! Yes, your notation is clearer. I will revise it.